# Beilinson and Deligne's Motivic Polylogarithm and Zagier Conjecture

Tags: reference-request, paper-request

Where can I find the preprint *Motivic Polylogarithm and Zagier Conjecture* by Beilinson and Deligne? I see it referenced in a lot of papers but no one seems to host a copy.

Comment: Is this the same? A. Beilinson and P. Deligne, *Interprétation motivique de la conjecture de Zagier reliant polylogarithmes et régulateurs*, in: U. Jannsen, S. Kleiman and J.-P. Serre (eds.),
*Motives*, Proceedings of Symposia in Pure Mathematics 55-2, American Mathematical Society (1994), 97-121.

Comment: I don't think so. They refer to the preprint in that paper